# Filter by a property that has a value of true in a collection of error objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an object that has a few different errors in it that are boolean. I would like to loop over this object and find out which errors are true and display their message that is also in the object, but not display the ones that are false.

I have tried to use the `.some()` and `.reduce()` functions but can't seem to get them to work.

```
const Errors = home => {
  const errors = [
    {
      message: 'This home requires an image.',
      error: true,
      buttonText: 'Add Image',
    },
    {
      message: 'This home requires two images.',
      error: false,
      buttonText: 'Add Image',
    },
    {
      message: 'This home was unpublished by the dealer.',
      error: true,
      buttonText: 'Publish Home',
    },
  ];

  return errors.some(error => error.message);
};

const MainComponent = () => {
  return(
    <Errors />
  );
}
```

I just want to display the errors that are true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter only the errors that are true and [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to show only the message

```
return errors.filter(e => e.error).map(e => e.message)
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks for the help.